# What is the difference between early hours in the morning and at dawn

Tags: difference

I want to make a sentence -

1. I get too tired to get up at dawn and go for work.
2. I get too tired to get up at early hours in the morning and go for work.

Is there any difference ? - Which one sounds better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, 'dawn' technically refers to a specific time - the twilight immediately before sunrise, where there is weak sunlight. So if you wanted to be completely correct, you would look outside tomorrow when you get up and see whether there's any sunlight visible yet. If the sun has just risen/is rising, you use sunrise, if there's twilight, you use dawn, otherwise use early hours of the morning.

In practice, however, the two terms are treated interchangeably, so you can say 'at dawn' or 'in the early hours of the morning' (**note**: not 'at the early hours of the morning') and be fine either way.

Personal preference, I tend to use dawn, but that's just because it's easier to say between yawns and mouthfuls of toast.